Not enough permissions to access: POST /simpleJobPostings
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/simpleJobPostings
for this particular I am getting below error
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: POST /simpleJobPostings",
"status": 403
}
In developers account, which product I need to request access ?
How to tackle this error ?
